# Filter a string on the basis of a word

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig job where in I need to filter the data by finding a word in it,

Here is the snippet

```
A = LOAD '/home/user/filename' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $27,$38;
C = FILTER B BY ( $1 ==  '*Word*');
STORE C INTO '/home/user/out1' USING PigStorage();
```

The error is in the 3rd line while finding C,
I have also tried using

```
C = FILTER B BY $1 MATCHES '*WORD*'
```

Also

```
C = FILTER B BY $1 MATCHES '\\w+WORD\\w+'
```

Comment: . Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
* zero or more times
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`MATCHES` uses regular expressions. You should do `... MATCHES '.*WORD.*'` instead.

These is an example [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#comparison) finding the word 'apache'.

Comment: that is the correct syntax, but I wonder why do we need to add the `.*` around the word. Why is `MATCHES 'WORD'` not working?